# Zip files using 7zip from command window

Tags: command-line, zip, 7zip

Using 7zip, I want to give a location of a folder of files something like...
D:\Home\files Then I want it to zip all the files in that folder and leave them there. So for example zipme.txt become zipme.zip, so all files would keep their name but just become a zip file. I have tried to use

```
FOR %i IN (D:\Home\files) DO 7z.exe a "%~ni.zip"
```

But when I do it it adds a zip file for the directory so my output would be in the correct folder but would contain

```
D:\Home\files\file.zip
D:\Home\files\zipme.zip
   zipped files also all items in directory like..
   zipme.txt
   zipme2.txt
D:\Home\files/zipme2.zip
```

So how can I zip each file individual in a folder and have the new zipped name be the individual files name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get this to work.

```
FOR %i IN (D:\Home\files\*) DO 7z.exe a "%~ni.zip" "%i"
```